# I get only same record on the gridview from the EWS undelivered email

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get all of the email from the EWS that i declare on the searchfilter, in console it showing all of the record but when i tried to view it to a webpage with a gridview it show up only the first record and it show more than 20+ the gridview. and here's my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmailMethods email = new EmailMethods();
    email.EmailServer = "https://SampleEWSEmail.asmx";
    email.AccountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Account"];
    email.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Secret"];
    email.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
    email.GetEmails();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Sender", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("DateSent", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("DateReceive", typeof(string));

    foreach (string item in email.EmailList)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(email.Subject, email.Sender, email.DateSent, email.DateReceive);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
}



public void GetEmails()
{
    if (EmailServer != "" && AccountName != "" && Password != "")
    {
        try
        {
            EmailList = new List<string>();
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(AccountName, Password, Domain);
            service.Url = new Uri(EmailServer);
            DisplayErrorEmails(service);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Status = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Status = "Please provide the Email Server, Account Name and Password.";
    }
}

private bool DisplayErrorEmails(ExchangeService service)
{
    try
    {
        FindItemsResults<item> findResults;
        SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection compoundFilter =
            new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or);
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Body, "Sorry, I couldn't find any host named", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The server is unable to connect", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Your outgoing message timed out because of issues concerning the incoming server.", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Invalid characters", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Access denied, spam abuse detected", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Access denied, banned sender", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The email account that you tried to reach does not exist", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The domain name in the email address is incorrect", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Host unknown or Domain lookup failed", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Mailbox full or Quota exceeded", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Mailbox unavailable", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Mailbox not found, Invalid mailbox, or User unknown", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "A time-out occurred while communicating with the server", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Timeout connection problem: there have been issues during the message transfer", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Connection refused or inability to open an SMTP stream", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The server cannot verify the user, but it will try to deliver the message anyway", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The service is unavailable due to a connection problem: it may refer to an exceeded limit of simultaneous connections, or a more general temporary problem", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The recipient's mailbox has exceeded its storage limi", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The recipient's Exchange Server incoming mail queue has been stopped", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The recipient's server is not responding", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The connection was dropped during the transmission", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The maximum hop count was exceeded for the message: an internal loop has occurred", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "A routing error", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Your ISP's server or the server that got a first relay from yours has encountered a connection problem", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Too many emails sent or too many recipients: more in general, a server storage limit exceeded", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "An error of your mail server, often due to an issue of the local anti-spam filter", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "A syntax error: the server couldn't recognize the command", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The command is not implemented", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The server has encountered a bad sequence of commands, or it requires an authentication", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "A command parameter is not implemented", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Bad email address", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "A DNS error: the host server for the recipient's domain name cannot be found", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Address type is incorrect: another problem concerning address misspelling.In few cases, however, it's related to an authentication issue", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The total size of your mailing exceeds the recipient server's limits", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "A problem occurred while delivering this message to this email address", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "This message hasn't been delivered yet", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The server could not be found", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Outlook is unable to connect to your outgoing (SMTP) e-mail server", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "The operation timed out waiting for a response from the receiving (POP) server", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "A time-out occurred while communicating with the server", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, "Delivery is delayed to these recipients or groups", ContainmentMode.ExactPhrase, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCaseAndNonSpacingCharacters));
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        //Displays the result
        ItemView view = new ItemView(100);
        do
        {
            findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, compoundFilter, view);
            foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
            {
                if (findResults.ToString() != "")
                {
                    EmailList.Add(Subject = item.Subject.ToString());
                    EmailList.Add(Sender = item.DisplayTo.ToString());
                    EmailList.Add(DateReceive = item.DateTimeReceived.ToString());
                    EmailList.Add(DateSent = item.DateTimeSent.ToString());
                }
            }
            if (findResults.NextPageOffset != null)
            {
                view.Offset = (int)findResults.NextPageOffset;
            }

        }while (findResults.MoreAvailable);

        Status = "list of undelivered email.";
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Status = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here's the sample record that it display on the gridview:

```
Subject Email   Receiver    Date and Time Sent  Date and Time Received
Undeliverable: crm  fdgdfgfdgf@fsfa.com 11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM   11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM
Undeliverable: crm  fdgdfgfdgf@fsfa.com 11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM   11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM
Undeliverable: crm  fdgdfgfdgf@fsfa.com 11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM   11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM
Undeliverable: crm  fdgdfgfdgf@fsfa.com 11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM   11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM
Undeliverable: crm  fdgdfgfdgf@fsfa.com 11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM   11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM
Undeliverable: crm  fdgdfgfdgf@fsfa.com 11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM   11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM
Undeliverable: crm  fdgdfgfdgf@fsfa.com 11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM   11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM
Undeliverable: crm  fdgdfgfdgf@fsfa.com 11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM   11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM
Undeliverable: crm  fdgdfgfdgf@fsfa.com 11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM   11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM
Undeliverable: crm  fdgdfgfdgf@fsfa.com 11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM   11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM
Undeliverable: crm  fdgdfgfdgf@fsfa.com 11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM   11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM
Undeliverable: crm  fdgdfgfdgf@fsfa.com 11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM   11/30/2017 9:15:11 PM
```

Comment: after this line `GridView1.DataBind();` add `GridView1.Refresh()` try that first..

Comment: you also need to review your code, you have an extra `}` at the end of the `Button1_Click` event .I would suggest using the debugger first and stepping thru the code setting multiple breakpoints also

Comment: i try that also and e check on the email.emailList and it count on all of the result and then i step on the next line it just only like rotating and it count only the first record.

Comment: The issue is here: `dt.Rows.Add(email.Subject, email.Sender, email.DateSent, email.DateReceive);`. Should be `item.Subject` and so on.

Comment: You are not using the loop variable. @AlexKudryashev has reason. You must use the variable **item**. Always when create a loop, we must to use the variable in the loop. I suggest alex to post this comment as response.

Comment: ok sir thanks, but when i used the item it did not show up the subject,sender and etc. but i'll be working on that again thanks for the information

Comment: when i tried to change something like this foreach (Item items in email.EmailList) im getting an error "Cannot convert type 'string' to Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.Item" is there other way to display to the gridview the result from the EmailMethods class?

Comment: Where do you declare the EmailList? Is this a Property of EmailMethods?

Comment: yes sir on the EmailMethods class.